# Proguard config when using luajava

Tags: android, proguard, luajava, androlua

Trying to Proguard my app that uses luajava (with AndroLua) and it runs fine until I proguard it and then it fails to start, i just get a black screen, and the logs fill up with the below entries which don't stop until app is uninstalled.

I'm using the standard SDK Proguard config and the follow config

```
-keep class org.keplerproject.luajava.**
```

Extract from log:

> 06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):          bea755d0  414f5fd8 
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted) 06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):
>   bea755d4  40af202d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapSourceAlloc(unsigned
>   int)+72) 06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):          bea755d8  414f5f30
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted) 06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):
>   bea755dc  bb99c9bb   06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):
>   bea755e0  00000000   06-21 10:07:23.781: I/DEBUG(156):
>   bea755e4  70b14afc  /data/app-lib/com.my.app-1/libluajava.so

Comment: @michal-kottman wondered if you'd come across any specific proguard config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the issue down to the `LuaState.java` the proguard config i was using kept the class but not the methods and I believe it's something to do with the proxyin of calls to lua. In any case the below proguard config worked

```
-keep class org.keplerproject.luajava.** { *; }
```